# Maven build breaks but dependency not in tree

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies

I have a build which runs fine on my local machine but is failing in Jenkins.

The build breaks with:

[WARNING] The POM for net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.16 is missing, no dependency information available

My project is not using this jar, it is not listed in my poms and does not show up when I run

mvn dependency:tree

no matter what debug/verbose options. There is no reference to neko in my code.

This is an initial setup within Jenkins so it could be that something is not configured quite right but I have no idea what it is - the build works fine on my local machine even using the same settings.xml as in Jenkins.

Comment: 1. This is a WARNING. Does it really break the build? 2. It may be a dependency of a maven plugin.

Comment: Good point, but it does stop the build. Are there options to ignore such warnings or find out what dependencies a plugin might need?

Comment: That is strange. Could you post the whole output of the build?

Comment: Could you please check if nekohtml appears in the Maven's output when started with -X flag? Next step would be to delete the folder ~/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/nekohtml and try again.